# :hover targeting not working exactly the way I want it to

Tags: html, css

if you hover over a project some text will appear, but if you mouse over the text it kills the hover style because that's not what triggers the hover.

```
p.description {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin: 40px 0 0 -125px; /*offset 50px from center*/
    transform: translateY(-50%); /*vertically centered*/
    width:250px;
    height:80px;
    z-index:1000;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
}
.holder:hover p.description {
    margin-top: 0; /*makes me slide up*/
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
p.description span {
    font-family: 'aileronbold';
    font-size: 110%;
}
```

This is my css for trying to accomplish this. I am not sure how to re-target to achieve this. Everything works as I want it minus when you mouse over the text.

You can check this at: http://darrenbachan.com/

Comment: I'm looking at your site, and I notice that the grey box appearing and the text sliding up are caused by the hovering of two different elements. (`a` => text, `div` => background) -- try combining these.

Comment: Oh, I should mention to make them both be on the `div` animation, as its animation is the one that stays even on text hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selector from `.holder a:hover` to `.holder:hover a`. You were seeing this flicker issue because the transition would end when you hover over the `p` description element that would transition in. By moving the `:hover` pseudo class to the parent element, the transition will remain intact even when you aren't hovering over the `a` element:

```
.holder:hover a {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
```

In order for the anchor element to be positioned over the `p` description element, you could absolutely position it *relative* to `.holder` (since it's relatively positioned).

```
.holder a {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Then remove `z-index: 1000` from `p.description`.

Comment: You and I found the same thing, I think.

Comment: @Darren The anchor element needs to be positioned over the `p` description element in order for it to be clickable. See the update..

Answer (score 1):

It is a `z-index` issue:

```
z-index: 9999; /* Or anything more than 1000 */
```

Give the above `z-index` to `.grow`:

```
.grow {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

And just because you are using `transition`, that jerk happens. Guess there's no way.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
.holder:hover p.description
```

to

```
.holder:hover p.description, p.description:hover
```

A little bit of a hack, but it'll work.

P.S. Love the site! Very pretty.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. I tried your change but it still behaves the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.holder a:hover {
   opacity:0;
}
```

To

```
.holder:hover a {
   opacity:0;
}
```

The key point is to prefix all hover style's selector with `.holder:hover`.